# Can I convert all the tensorflow slim models to tflite?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, tensorflow-lite

I'm training tensorflow slim based models for image classification on a custom dataset. Before I invest a lot of time training such huge a dataset, I wanted to know whether or not can I convert all the models available in the [slim model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim) to tflite format.

Also, I know that I can convert my custom slim-model to a frozen graph. It is the step after this which I'm worried about i.e, conversion to .tflite from my custom trained .pb model.

Is this supported ? or is there anyone who is facing conversion problems that has not yet been resolved ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many Slim models can be converted to TFLite, but it isn't a guarantee since some models might have ops not supported by TFLite.

What you could do, is try and convert your model to TensorFlow Lite using [TFLiteConverter](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/python_api) in Python before training. If the conversion succeeds, then you can train your TF model and convert it once again.